# Iteratively-defined Numpy Array Creation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration, filtering

I'm having trouble phrasing this problem in Numpy.  I need to simulate an analog maximum tracker (resistor diode capacitor).  I have some very long 1-D array X from which I want to calculate the output array Y, such that

```
Y[0] = X[0]
Y[i] = max(0.99 * Y[i - 1], X[i])
```

I've faked it by approximating my above rules with `Y^30 = ExpDecayFunc * X^30` where the asteriks is convolution.  Surely there is something much more straight forward I'm missing?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to simulate an asymmetric signal filter (resistor, diode, capacitor)? It is a nasty non-linear operation, which cannot be calculated in parallel. So, this is really not something nice for NumPy to solve.

The trivial solution is:

```
import numpy as np

# just do something random
X = np.random.random(1000000)

def my_filter(X):
    Y = np.empty(len(X))
    Y[0] = X[0]
    for i in range(1, len(X)):
        Y[i] = max(.99*Y[i-1], X[i])
    return Y
```

This takes time, my machine needs whopping 1.36 s for this (1.36 us for item). Not very nice. (**Edit**: The stupid use of `np.arange` changed to `range`.)

The algorithm can be made a bit faster by rearranging it to avoid lookups:

```
def my_filter_2(X):
    Y = np.empty(len(X))
    Y[0] = X[0]
    a = .99 * Y[0]
    for i in range(1, len(X)):
        a = max(a, X[i])
        Y[i] = a
        a *= .99
    return Y
```

Now we have 1.16 ms (1.16 us per element). An improvement, but not very fast after all.

But then we have `cython`. This is done with IPython's `%%cython` (not my solution, `Andrew Jaffe` shows this in his great answer):

```
%%cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

# just do something random
cdef np.ndarray cX =  np.random.random(1000000)

def cy_filter(np.ndarray[np.double_t] X):
    cdef int i
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t] Y = np.empty(len(X))
    Y[0] = X[0]
    for i in range(1, len(X)):
        Y[i] = max(.99*Y[i-1], X[i])
    return Y
```

This is fast! My computer claims 6.43 ms (6.43 ns/element).

Another almost-Pythonic solution is `numba` as suggested by `DSM` in their answer:

```
from numba import autojit
import numpy as np

@autojit
def my_filter_nb(X, Y):
    Y[0] = X[0]
    for i in range(1, len(X)):
        Y[i] = max(.99*Y[i-1], X[i])
    return Y

def my_filter_fast(X):
    Y = np.empty(len(X))
    my_filter_nb(X, Y)
    return Y
```

This gives 4.18 ms (4.18 ns/element).

But if we still need speed, let's C:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.weave

X = np.random.random(1000000)

def my_filter_c(X):
    x_len = len(X)
    Y = np.empty(x_len)

    c_source = """
        #include <math.h>

        int i;
        double a, x;

        Y(0) = X(0);
        a = .99 * Y(0);
        for (i = 1; i < x_len; i++)
            {
            x = X(i); 
            if (x > a)
                a = x;
            Y(i) = a;
            a *= .99;
            }
        """

    scipy.weave.inline(c_source, ["X","Y","x_len"], 
        compiler="gcc", 
        headers=["<math.h>"],
        type_converters=scipy.weave.converters.blitz)

    return Y
```

This one gives 3.72 ms (3.72 ns/round). (BTW, my brain is not multi-threaded, and writing inlined C into Python would require two threads - it's amazing how many semicolons one can miss when writing a simple program in C.) The improvement is not that big, the trouble is.

To see how bad or good this is compared to plain C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUMITER 100000000

int main(void)
    {
    double *x, *y;
    double a, b, time_delta;
    int i;
    struct rusage ru0, ru1;

    x = (double *)malloc(NUMITER * sizeof(double));
    y = (double *)malloc(NUMITER * sizeof(double));
    for (i = 0; i < NUMITER; i++)
        x[i] = rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX - 1);

    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &ru0);
    y[0] = x[0];
    a = .99 * y[0];
    for (i = 0; i < NUMITER; i++)
        {
        b = x[i]; 
        if (b > a)
        a = b;
        y[i] = a;
        a *= .99;
        }
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &ru1);

    time_delta = ru1.ru_utime.tv_sec + ru1.ru_utime.tv_usec * 1e-6 
               - ru0.ru_utime.tv_sec - ru0.ru_utime.tv_usec * 1e-6;
    printf("Took %.6lf seconds, %.2lf nanoseconds per element", time_delta, 1e9 * time_delta / NUMITER);

    return (int)y[1234] % 2; // just to make sure the optimizer is not too clever
    }
```

This compiled with `gcc -Ofast` takes 318 ms or 3.18 ns/element (note the larger number of elements) and is thus the winner.

All Python timings have been performed with IPython's `%timeit` and they include some overhead from the `np.empty`, but that is quite insignificant. However probably due to memory management issues the results vary somewhat from one run to another, so they need to be taken with a pinch a salt in any case.

I also tried the faster solutions with 500 million elements to avoid call overheads:

- `%cython`: 7.5 ns/element
- `numba`: 7.3 ns/element
- inlined C (weave): 5.7 ns/element
- plain C: 3.2 ns/element

I also tried some hand-optimizing tricks with plain C, but at least without looking at the compiling results it seems that `gcc` is at least as clever as I am.

Out of this stack I'd probably take `numba` or plain C depending on the rush I am having. With this specific problem `scipy.weave.inline` is too much trouble compared to the advantage.

Also -- depending on the data -- this could possibly be made slightly faster with parallel processing, but the worst case is then worse, and the whole thing may be memory-bandwidth-limited anyway.

Comment: Thanks @DrV your confirmation that this is hard to do in native numpy was exactly what I was looking for!  Great snippets.

Answer (score 1):

[Cython](http://cython.org) is very fast. I ran this in iPython using the [cython magic](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3607712653c66d63e0d7f13f073bde8c0f209ba8/docs/examples/notebooks/cython_extension.ipynb).

```
%% cython   

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

# just do something random
cdef np.ndarray cX =  np.random.random(1000000)

def cy_filter(np.ndarray[np.double_t] X):
    cdef int i
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t] Y = np.empty(len(X))
    Y[0] = X[0]
    for i in range(1, len(X)):
        Y[i] = max(.99*Y[i-1], X[i])
    return Y
```

Using `%timeit`, I get a speedup from

```
1 loops, best of 3: 1.52 s per loop
```

to

```
100 loops, best of 3: 4.67 ms per loop
```

(For what it's worth, when I missed the `cdef int i` it was only about a factor 3 speedup, instead of 300!)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Its funny how much that one cdef counts for.  I would have naively expected cython to know range must return a ctype integer.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe: Great answer! I included it into my answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/), although it would require a few changes:

```
from numba import autojit
import numpy as np

@autojit
def my_filter_nb(X, Y):
    Y[0] = X[0]
    for i in range(1, len(X)):
        Y[i] = max(.99*Y[i-1], X[i])
    return Y

def my_filter_fast(X):
    Y = np.empty(len(X))
    my_filter_nb(X, Y)
    return Y

def my_filter(X):
    Y = np.empty(len(X))
    Y[0] = X[0]
    for i in np.arange(1, len(X)):
        Y[i] = max(.99*Y[i-1], X[i])
    return Y
```

which gives me:

```
>>> X = np.random.random(1000000)
>>> %timeit my_filter(X)
1 loops, best of 3: 936 ms per loop
>>> %timeit my_filter_fast(X)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.83 ms per loop
>>> (my_filter(X) == my_filter_fast(X)).all()
True
```

Comment: Never seen numba before, I'll have to go check it out!

Comment: @DSM: I am impressed! IMHO this is the winner in this case due to the cleanness of the code. (I included this into my answer, as well.)